# pcl-ros compilation issue: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'

Tags: ros, pcl, boost, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

.
Hi, I am trying to install ROS with PCL and compile it in ubuntu 11.10.

$svn info

Path: .
URL: https://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_electric_unstable
Repository Root: https://svn.pointclouds.org/ros
Repository UUID: 96ee21a3-c2b3-4322-a94e-acd7bc47b802
Revision: 265
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: atrevor
Last Changed Rev: 253
Last Changed Date: 2012-04-06 04:27:41 +0530 (Fri, 06 Apr 2012)

### $rosmake perception_pcl_electric_unstable
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/swagatika/Documents/Robotic_Vision/codes/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl_ros/build' [ 16%] Built target pcl_ros_tf Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/pcd_to_pointcloud make[3]: Entering directory` /home/swagatika/Documents/Robotic_Vision/codes/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl_ros/build'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/swagatika/Documents/Robotic_Vision/codes/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl_ros/build' make[3]: Entering directory` /home/swagatika/Documents/Robotic_Vision/codes/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl_ros/build'
Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/pointcloud_to_pcd
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../bin/convert_pointcloud_to_image] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/swagatika/Documents/Robotic_Vision/codes/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl_ros/build' make[2]: *** [src/tools/CMakeFiles/convert_pointcloud_to_image.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()' /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()' /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[3]: *** [../bin/pointcloud_to_pcd] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/swagatika/Documents/Robotic_Vision/codes/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl_ros/build'
make[2]: *** [src/tools/CMakeFiles/pointcloud_to_pcd.dir/all] Error 2
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../bin/pcd_to_pointcloud] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/swagatika/Documents/Robotic_Vision/codes/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl_ros/build' make[2]: *** [src/tools/CMakeFiles/pcd_to_pointcloud.dir/all] Error 2 /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()' /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()' /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[3]: *** [../bin/convert_pcd_to_image] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/swagatika/Documents/Robotic_Vision/codes/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl_ros/build'
make[2]: *** [src/tools/CMakeFiles/convert_pcd_to_image.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/swagatika/Documents/Robotic_Vision/codes/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl_ros/build' make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/swagatika/Documents/Robotic_Vision/codes/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl_ros/build'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package pcl_ros written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/swagatika/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120819-234013/pcl_ros/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_ros [FAIL] [ 6.50 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pcl_ros.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 102 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/swagatika/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120819-234013
[ rosmake ] WARNING: Rosdep did not detect the following system dependencies as installed: libvtk-qt Consider using --rosdep-install option or `rosdep install flann pcl pcl_ros cminpack`

I have Boost 1.46.1 installed in my system.

Please help in sorting it out.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41846/pcl-ros-compilation-issue:-undefined-reference-to-%27boost::system::generic_category()%27/) by [swagatika](https://answers.ros.org/users/3054/swagatika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

It seems that the issue is with the linker which is not able to link your project to the boost directories. A quick and simple edit in your CMakelists.txt should enable the linking of the necessary boost directories.

You might have to uncomment the following line in Cmakelists:

> rosbuild_add_boost_directories()

Next you will also have to add the following line:

> rosbuild_link_boost(***Binary_File_Name*** signals)

> rosbuild_link_boost(***Binary_File_Name*** systems)

Binary_File_Name is the name of the executable and the above lines have to be added after the rosbuild_add_executable() line. In most cases your rosmake should work fine after these corrections. You may search your error in Google for more information on this.

Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) with karma: 612 on 2012-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0